# get element in html which was opened ViewController.openExternalView by using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, dojo

I tried to display the page2.html when click the `Show Image` in page1.html. I use ViewController.openExternalView to display page2.html because `dijit.registry.byId("myPage1").performTransition('myPage2', 1, "slide", null);` is not working.

When the page2 displays, I change the visibility of the image in page2 to visible. But the `document.getElementById('myImgId')` return null.

It seems script execute before page2.html is loaded. Is there anyway to execute script to able to get elements safely?

dojo version: 1.9.3

Following is the snippet that I'm trying.

javascript

```
function showImage(){
 var vc = dojox.mobile.ViewController.getInstance();
 vc.openExternalView({
  url:"page2.html",
  transition:"slide"
 },dijit.registry.byId("container").containerNode);
 document.getElementById("myImgId").style.vilibility="visible";
}
```

page1.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="myPage1">
 ----some html tags----
 <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="variableHeight:true" >
  <div onclick="showImage();"><label>Show Image</label></div>
  <div>
   ----some more html tags----
   </div>
 </li>
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="myPage2">
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Container">
  <img src="img1.png" id="myImgId" style="vilibility:hidden;"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function showImage(){
 var vc = dojox.mobile.ViewController.getInstance();
 Deferred.when(vc.openExternalView({
  url:"page2.html",
  transition:"slide"
 },dijit.registry.byId("container").containerNode), function(){
     document.getElementById("myImgId").style.vilibility="visible";
 });     
}
```

Comment: I added `Deferred.when()` to `dojo.Deferred.when()` when I got an error "deferred is not defined". After that, it is working. Thanks @edchat